# Split the data in php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a variabe named $link in PHP that repeats itself and it has data like:

```
  http://www.ankinfos.com/our-portfolio/www.abc.com
     http://www.ankinfos.com/our-portfolio/www.cab.com
 http://www.ankinfos.com/our-portfolio/www.zzz.com

.
.
.
.
 http://www.ankinfos.com/our-portfolio/www.lal.com
```

I want to remove the text or data before www.abc.com so that it becomes

```
 http://www.ankinfos.com/our-portfolio/www.abc.com
```

to

```
www.abc.com
```

and
     http://www.ankinfos.com/our-portfolio/www.abc.com

to

```
www.cab.com
```

and so on

Please let me know any solution for that in jquery or php

Comment: str_replace() will do this fine

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way in php is to do

```
$url = "http://.../www.abc.com";
$url = explode('/', $url);
$yourUrl = $url[count($url) - 1];
```

As for javascript:

```
var url = "http://.../www.abc.com";
url = url.split("/");
var yourUrl = url[url.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` function in javascript

```
var fullLink = "http://www.ankinfos.com/our-portfolio/www.abc.com";

var url = fullLink.split('/');
url = url[url.length-1]

alert(url)​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gsruv/

And `explode()` in PHP

Comment: I think your javascript would result in ".ankinfos.com/our-portfolio/"

Comment: `split` has been deprecated, you'd better use `explode`.

Comment: Sorry, but `split` is deprecated in PHP but not in JS and I already suggested explode for PHP

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$myArray = explode("http://www.ankinfos.com/our-portfolio/", $link);
array_shift($myArray);
print_r($myArray);
```

This will explode each url (Which I assume is constant) and will remove it's first element (since the delimiter is at the start, it will cause an empty string to be placed as the first item).

Now, you can iterate the items.